# I cannot connect from my cloud kafka to databricks community edition's spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, databricks, databricks-community-edition

1- I have a spark cluster on databricks community edition and I have a Kafka instance on GCP.

2- I just want to data ingestion Kafka streaming from databricks community edition and I want to analyze the data on spark.

[image: Kafka and nifi's external ip]

3-
This is my connection code.

```
val UsYoutubeDf = 
       spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "XXX.XXX.115.52:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "usyoutube")
      .load`
```

As is mentioned my datas arriving to the kafka.
I'm entering firewall settings **spark.driver.host** otherwise ı cannot sending any ping to my kafka machine from databricks's cluster
[image: My temporary spark machine's ip]

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger.ProcessingTime
 
val sortedModelCountQuery = sortedyouTubeSchemaSumDf
                          .writeStream
                          .outputMode("complete")
                          .format("console")
                          .option("truncate","false")
                          .trigger(ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
                          .start()
```

After this post the datas dont coming to my spark on cluster

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger.ProcessingTime
sortedModelCountQuery: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@3bd8a775
```

It stays like this. Actually, the data is coming, but the code I wrote for analysis does not work here

Comment: Ping doesn't check your Kafka listeners are correctly defined. https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @OneCricketeer so, what should ı do ? Whats your recommendation ?

Comment: Read the blog? Adjust your kafka server properties accordingly. It's not a Spark problem

Comment: OK, so your connection works from spark to Kafka? I can see that you mentioned that your data is received in Kafka for the connection.
My understanding is that the problem you have is because you are not receiving the data after the initial connection is completed. You might want to check this documentation:
 https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html